# Beaglebone Black - Maximum current supplied by 1.8V analog rail (Pin P9_32)?

Tags: voltage-divider, beaglebone-black

On the Beaglebone Black, what is the most current that the 1.8V analog rail (pin 32 on header P9) can supply?

I can't find it in the [System Reference Manual](https://github.com/CircuitCo/BeagleBone-Black/blob/rev_b/BBB_SRM.pdf). I would've expected to find it in section 6.1.9, "Power Rails".

I want to use it with a voltage divider to get a 0.9V source. I plan to use it like this:

[image]

With two 10k resistors and the op-amp buffer, the current should be 90 uA -- very small.

Comment: I would be *extremely* surprised if you were unable to draw 90uA from it.

Comment: Why not use a standard linear voltage regulator, or a voltage reference if your 0.9V supply doesn't need to provide much current?

Comment: @helloworld922, I suppose I could do that. Are you suggesting using (say) a 5V voltage regulator and voltage-dividing it to 0.9V, similar to the picture above? The appeal of using the BB is that I'm using this 0.9V signal to level-shift a (possibly negative voltage) signal to the 0-to-1.8V range required by the BB's analog inputs. So I was thinking it would be nice to have the 0.9V also generated by the BB. Also, what is a "voltage reference"? Sorry, I'm new at this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the current capability of that pin, you need to look in the Sitara datasheet. The pin is called VDDA_ADC, and is specified for 10 milliamps.

However, I would not recommend putting a voltage divider on that signal without a buffer. Although that pin is often referred to as a "rail", it is actually the reference voltage to the ADC, so using it directly will add a path for noise into all eight ADC channels.

I would recommend adding an additional op-amp to buffer it prior to using it.